# Setting Kinesis Firehose as target for CloudWatch Events Rule in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm making a CloudFormation template to capture the components of a process where CloudWatch Events are sent to a Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream. (It's working in AWS fine manually configured through the console.)

When I define the [AWS::Events::Rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html) there is a [Targets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html#cfn-events-rule-targets) property that expects the ARN of a valid target. The problem is that a `AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream` resource does not support retrieving its ARN and `Fn::Ref` just returns its logical ID. ([Fn::GetAtt](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) can be used to get the ARN of a `AWS::Kinesis::Stream` but there is nothing for `AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream`.)

Am I going about something the wrong way or is this just one of those things that is not yet supported by CloudFormation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to build the DeliveryStream ARN based on the [ARN namespace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-kinesis-firehose) for Kinesis Firehose

Something like the following assuming the `AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream` resource is called `DeliveryStream`(not tested)

```
{"Fn::Sub": [
    "arn:aws:firehose:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:deliverystream/${DeliveryStream}",
    {
      "DeliveryStream": {"Ref": "DeliveryStream"}
    }
  ]}
```

Since the [return value](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream.html#aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-returnvalues) on `AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream` is the Delivery Stream name

Comment: Quick update `AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream` now returns the ARN. So you can use `!GetAtt DeliveryStream.Arn` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream.html#aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-return-values